# How to filter prometheus query results based on the maximum value in a time range?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I am monitoring a series of CPU load data, which is aggregated. Similar to:

```
avg(load_data{}) by (service_name)
```

Now, I just want to filter out the results that meet the following conditions: In the past n days, the maximum value of one service is greater than 90%.

My purpose is to focus on the service who had a high CPU usage.

How can I do that? I tried max_over_time() but not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use subquery, like this:

```
max_over_time(avg by (service_name) (load_data)[1d:])
```

More info in the Prometheus documentation [here](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/).